# Venting a basement range hood

Tags: hvac

I have a new range hood located in close proximity to the through the roof vent for the furnace and hot water tank; can I tap into that vent pipe for the range hood?

Answer (score 1):

The venting for the furnace and water heater have to be separate from any other venting. You do not want backfeed from your furnace/water heater in through your range hood.

Comment: Also, you also don't want fat accumulation on the lining of your furnace chimney, or food particles backfeeding into your burners.   Also, the range hood vent does not have to be so heat tolerant and does not have to go through the roof, it should be easy to find a path for it to an outside wall.  And, the furnace may have a motorized flue baffle with a failsafe switch whereas the range hood baffle is probably a gravity-operated flap.  These are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Could you run the vent from the range thru a dedicated pipe parallel to the furnace vent and just enlarge the opening to accommodate the new pipe?